# Daisy chaining not working anymore after running update

Tags: apt, 18.04, multiple-monitors, display

I'm running a Dell Precision 5530 with Ubuntu 18.04 which is connected to a 24" Dell monitor through a mini-display-port to display-port cable, which is connected to a 24" Dell monitor through a display-port to mini-display-port cable using daisy chaning.

Until yesterday, everything worked as expected, however, I did an `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade` and after that the daisy chaining doesn't work anymore.

So, in general I have three monitors

1. Built-in
2. 24" connected from Laptop (1) to this monitor (2)
3. 24" connected from monitor (2) to this monitor (3).

If 3 is turned off, 1 and 2 work as expected, however, as soon as I turn on 3, not even 2 works anymore. 2 is always shown in the settings under displays, but is black when 3 is on. 3 is never in the settings.

This is the update log from this morning

```
Start-Date: 2018-11-05  08:04:34
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.113'
Install: linux-headers-4.15.0-38-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-38.41, automatic), linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-38-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-38.41, automatic), linux-modules-4.15.0-38-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-38.41, automatic), linux-headers-4.15.0-38:amd64 (4.15.0-38.41, automatic), linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-38.41, automatic)
Upgrade: libpackagekit-glib2-18:amd64 (1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.1, 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.3), update-manager-core:amd64 (1:18.04.11.5, 1:18.04.11.6), networkd-dispatcher:amd64 (1.7-0ubuntu3.2, 1.7-0ubuntu3.3), linux-headers-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.36.38, 4.15.0.38.40), friendly-recovery:amd64 (0.2.38, 0.2.38ubuntu1), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.15.0-36.39, 4.15.0-38.41), libapt-inst2.0:amd64 (1.6.3ubuntu0.1, 1.6.6), yarn:amd64 (1.10.1-1, 1.12.1-1), grub-common:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.6, 2.02-2ubuntu8.7), linux-image-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.36.38, 4.15.0.38.40), apt:amd64 (1.6.3ubuntu0.1, 1.6.6), libparted2:amd64 (3.2-20, 3.2-20ubuntu0.1), update-manager:amd64 (1:18.04.11.5, 1:18.04.11.6), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (70.0.3538.67-1, 70.0.3538.77-1), python-apt-common:amd64 (1.6.2, 1.6.3), grub2-common:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.6, 2.02-2ubuntu8.7), gdm3:amd64 (3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.1, 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.3), libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 (1.6.3ubuntu0.1, 1.6.6), packagekit-tools:amd64 (1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.1, 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.3), grub-pc:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.6, 2.02-2ubuntu8.7), libparted-fs-resize0:amd64 (3.2-20, 3.2-20ubuntu0.1), linux-signed-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.36.38, 4.15.0.38.40), gir1.2-gdm-1.0:amd64 (3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.1, 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.3), grub-pc-bin:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.6, 2.02-2ubuntu8.7), libgdm1:amd64 (3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.1, 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.3), dpkg:amd64 (1.19.0.5ubuntu2, 1.19.0.5ubuntu2.1), nautilus:amd64 (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.1, 1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.2), libnautilus-extension1a:amd64 (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.1, 1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.2), grub-efi-amd64-bin:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.6, 2.02-2ubuntu8.7), python3-distupgrade:amd64 (1:18.04.26, 1:18.04.27), man-db:amd64 (2.8.3-2, 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1), python3-update-manager:amd64 (1:18.04.11.5, 1:18.04.11.6), gir1.2-snapd-1:amd64 (1.41-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 1.43-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (1:18.04.26, 1:18.04.27), gitlab-runner:amd64 (11.3.1, 11.4.2), parted:amd64 (3.2-20, 3.2-20ubuntu0.1), packagekit:amd64 (1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.1, 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.3), apt-utils:amd64 (1.6.3ubuntu0.1, 1.6.6), mokutil:amd64 (0.3.0-0ubuntu5, 0.3.0+1538710437.fb6250f-0ubuntu2~18.04.1), light-themes:amd64 (16.10+18.04.20180421.1-0ubuntu1, 16.10+18.04.20181005-0ubuntu1), ubuntu-artwork:amd64 (1:16.10+18.04.20180421.1-0ubuntu1, 1:16.10+18.04.20181005-0ubuntu1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:amd64 (1:18.04.26, 1:18.04.27), grub-efi-amd64-signed:amd64 (1.93.7+2.02-2ubuntu8.6, 1.93.8+2.02-2ubuntu8.7), gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0:amd64 (1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.1, 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.3), nautilus-data:amd64 (1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.1, 1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.2), apt-transport-https:amd64 (1.6.3ubuntu0.1, 1.6.6), libsnapd-glib1:amd64 (1.41-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, 1.43-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), gstreamer1.0-packagekit:amd64 (1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.1, 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.3), libdpkg-perl:amd64 (1.19.0.5ubuntu2, 1.19.0.5ubuntu2.1), secureboot-db:amd64 (1.1, 1.4~ubuntu0.18.04.1), linux-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.36.38, 4.15.0.38.40), ubuntu-mono:amd64 (16.10+18.04.20180421.1-0ubuntu1, 16.10+18.04.20181005-0ubuntu1), python3-apt:amd64 (1.6.2, 1.6.3), dpkg-dev:amd64 (1.19.0.5ubuntu2, 1.19.0.5ubuntu2.1)
End-Date: 2018-11-05  08:05:28

Start-Date: 2018-11-05  08:06:19
Commandline: apt upgrade
Requested-By: tzfrs (1000)
Upgrade: gnome-software-plugin-snap:amd64 (3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.3, 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.4), gnome-software:amd64 (3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.3, 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.4), ubuntu-software:amd64 (3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.3, 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.4), unattended-upgrades:amd64 (1.1ubuntu1.18.04.5, 1.1ubuntu1.18.04.6), gnome-software-common:amd64 (3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.3, 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.4)
End-Date: 2018-11-05  08:06:23
```

This is both on X11 and Wayland. Steps I did

- Re-plug the cable
- Turn off/on monitors
- Restart
- Log out

Update: I just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10, hoping this would solve the issue, however, the issue still exists.